# PHP/Jquery: Using value of clicked element in a function

Tags: php, jquery

I have an element of label class

```
<li><a><span class='label'>$element</span></a></li>
```

and I want to be able to run `loadStuff` onclick. How do I get the value of the clicked element to pass in like:

```
$(".label").click(loadStuff(valueOfClickedElement));
```

Comment: Please feel free to accept/upvote best suited answer. [Read more about accepting answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you say value, I assume you meant text of the span..

If so, then  try below,

```
$(".label").click(function () {
   loadStuff($(this).text());
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$(".label").click(function() { 
    loadStuff($(this).text()); 
});
```